# Making menu items invisible from on the master page

Tags: asp.net, menu, master-pages, sitemap

I have a menu using a sitemap that is in my master page.  I want to disable certain menu items depending on the user.  Under no circumstances do I want to go down the rabbit hole of MS "roles".

I have the following Site.Master:

```
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" 
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              CssClass="menu"
              StaticDisplayLevels="1"
              StaticMenuItemStyle-VerticalPadding="2"
              StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding="10"
              StaticMenuItemStyle-Font-Name="Verdana"
              StaticMenuItemStyle-Font-Size="12pt"
              StaticHoverStyle-BackColor="#707070"
              StaticHoverStyle-ForeColor="#550000"

              DynamicMenuStyle-HorizontalPadding="2"
              DynamicMenuStyle-VerticalPadding="2"
              DynamicMenuStyle-BackColor="#E0E0E0"
              DynamicMenuStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF"
              DynamicMenuStyle-BorderWidth="1"
              DynamicMenuStyle-BorderColor="#C0C0C0"
              DynamicMenuItemStyle-VerticalPadding="2"
              DynamicMenuItemStyle-Font-Name="Verdana"
              DynamicMenuItemStyle-Font-Size="9pt"
              DynamicMenuItemStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF"
              DynamicHoverStyle-BackColor="#707070"
              DynamicHoverStyle-ForeColor="#550000" />               


            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server"  ShowStartingNode="False" />
```

I have web.sitemap similar to the following:

```
<siteMapNode >
    <siteMapNode url="default.aspx" title="Home"  description="" />

    <siteMapNode url="default.aspx?p=0" title="Admin" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="default.aspx?p=55" title="thing1"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="default.aspx?p=56" title="thing2"  description="" />
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="default.aspx?p=1" title="Thing3"   description="">
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="default.aspx?p=2" title="Thing4"  description="">
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
```

In Site.Master.cs I tried adding the following code under both Page_Load AND under MainMenu_MenuItemDataBound:

```
Response.Write(MainMenu.Items.Count.ToString());
```

When I put it under MainMenu_MenuItemDataBound, it has no effect.
When I put it under Page_Load() it prints zero, even though I can SEE the menu displayed correctly and it DOES have items!

Facts:
The menu exists.
The menu has items.
The menu and items display correctly so far as it goes.

I want to go in and, for example, make the item with Title "Admin" invisible (along with it's submenu items) - I would like to remove it, but either making it invisible or disabling it would be okay.  I've tried various incantations involving MainMenu.FindItem ... which method doesn't seem to have any relation to finding items.  This is when I noticed that the reason it's not finding any items is because the item count is zero (even though I can see the items).

Solution as per Dave D below, but also needed to add

```
OnMenuItemDataBound="MainMenu_MenuItemDataBound"
```

to the MainMenu tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Menu will not be bound to the data yet in the page_load.  Thats why it does not have a count.

Checking the item in the MenuItemDataBound as they are bound can be done like this:

```
protected void MainMenu_MenuItemDataBound(Object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.Text == "Admin")
    {
        // disable the item
        //e.Item.Enabled = false;

        // remove the menu item
        MainMenu.Items.Remove(e.Item);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did not work.  As near as I can tell, MainMenu_MenuItemDataBound is never invoked.

Comment: AH!  The secret was I needed to add
        OnMenuItemDataBound="MainMenu_MenuItemDataBound"
to the tag for MainMenu.  So your solution does work.